# Development environment for embedded system

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I need to develop software in C/C++ for an embedded system. I have Debian 6 running off of a USB hard drive. I would like to be able to generate a stripped-down kernel with modules, and install them either on a CF card or a USB 'thumb' drive.

I succeeded in building a Linux 3.6 kernel and running it in Debian off of the USB hard drive, but I am having trouble figuring out how to install it on the thumb drive.

I would like a build cycle that looks like this:

1) Build module or kernel with desired software
2) Install it on thumb drive
3) Boot and test

I would like to use the same system for both development and testing, if that is feasible. I am looking for resources and tutorials that would help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your host (development system) is not your target system, then look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).
A 30-slide intro on features of Buildroot is [here](http://free-electrons.com/docs/buildroot/)
At the end (#27) there is mention of a few similar and alternate tools to build embedded systems.

If your host (development) and target are the same system , then look at the [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/index.html) tutorial and [friends](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Your title has the broad concept of "development environment", but then you mention "writing to thumb drive".  Is the issue really creating a bootable root filesystem?
You have not written an actual question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429068/buildroot-built-a-file-system-how-to-login-boot-hangs

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm not 100% sure I know what I'm looking for, but this answer gave me some addition resources which may get me what I need. The Linux From Scratch tutorial looks like it may do the trick. I have used *nix on and off for several years, but never had to get into the admin stuff or kernel-level programming, so picking up the various concepts is like sipping from a firehose.